# Is there a way to stop eclipse search from duplicating results

Tags: eclipse

This is a really minor issue but I thought I'd stop ignoring it and see if there is an easy resolution.  In Eclipse Oxygen.2 I have a Java app with a number of sub projects which I tend to look at in JavaEE view (presumably irrelevant to the search results).  When I do a file search (*.java) I get each file twice.  One under parent_project\project and once under project.  This is a little irritating and made more so because the intellisense and code 'go to' facilities don't work in the files displayed under parent_project\project.

I just wondered if I was missing a really obvious way to stop this happening ?

Comment: Obviously, you missed upgrading Eclipse for a few years. You are six releases behind.

Comment: ahhh okay so it's 'fixed' in later versions?  Sadly we are on locked down machine so I have to use the company approved version.

Comment: To try it with the current version is up to you (before asking). And yes, the file search has been improved since Oxygen.2 (plus 2019-09 contains Quick Search). _"... the company approved version"_?! Someone in your company doesn't seem to get what the Eclipse Foundation is for (everything that can be downloaded directly from eclipse.org is IP checked). Talk to that person.

Comment: Maybe but then Oxygen.2 is a pretty mature version of Eclipse with a mature & established build tool (maven) so I was surprised the search results were producing duplicates, even if it was released 2 years ago.  Can't complain seeing as it's free but thought it might be a setting I was missing rather than something everyone lived with for years... Not arguing about all the dev tools being locked down though, agree it's silly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know since when this feature is implemented in Eclipse, but on 2020-09 version you can use "Filter duplicated resources" on the Ctrl+R search options :

[image: Filter option]